# How to hit the multiple url within same session and with one authentication in java

Tags: java, rest, session, authentication

I have to hit one rest url and before that i am hitting another rest url for loginn purposes by passing username/password. I am getting 200 OK from the first url. Now when i am trying to consume another REST url it's giving me 401 error.Code is as follows"

```
    String urlParameters  = "username=a&password=b&rememberme=false";
    byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
    int    postDataLength = postData.length;
    URL url = new URL("myloginurl");
    HttpURLConnection  con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
    con.setUseCaches( false );
    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream())) {
       wr.write( postData );
    }
    int respCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if(respCode==200){
        urlParameters = "id=x&col1=y&op1=z&val1=t";
        postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        postDataLength = postData.length;
        url = new URL("myanotherurl");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        con.setUseCaches( false );
        try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write( postData );
        }
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
    }
```

Can anybody please point out where i am doing the mistake. Also let me know is there any better way to write this code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server should return a session id in the form of a new cookie in your first request. You have to include that cookie in your second request, so that the server can identify you. The cookie is sent within the http headers.

After you get the responsecode from the first request, you can fetch the new cookie values like:

```
  String cookieValue = con.getHeaderFields()
    .getOrDefault("Set-Cookie", Collections.emptyList())
    .stream()
    .map(str -> str.split(";")[0])
    .collect(joining("; "));
```

Then you use that value for the cookies in the next request like:

```
 con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieValue);
```

Comment: What is this joining in collect(joining("; "))

Comment: That is a static method of Collectors and just joins multiple cookie values together with '; ' as separator. It is used in case there are more Set-Cookie header field.